# Run webservice with Spring and Axis: unrecognized method

Tags: web-services, spring, tomcat, soap, axis

I've a Spring-based web application and I need to expose a webservice using Axis. I followed [this guide](http://java-x.blogspot.it/2007/01/implementing-web-services-with-spring.html) but service still doesn't work properly. **To resume**, I have an EndPoint class like this:

```
package service;

import org.springframework.remoting.jaxrpc.ServletEndpointSupport;

public class SpringWSEndPoint extends ServletEndpointSupport implements ISpringWS {
private ISpringWS springWS;

protected void onInit() {
 this.springWS = (ISpringWS) getWebApplicationContext().getBean("springWS");
}

public String sayHello(String message) {
 return springWS.sayHello(message);
}
}
```

and servlet mapped like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>WSSpring</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
 <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<listener>
 <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>axis</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>5</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>axis</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/axis/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Thus, once I navigate `http://localhost:8080/myProject/axis/SpringWSEndPoint?wsdl` it comes out with a (seems properly) auto-generated wsdl, as expected.

**But if I go to `http://localhost:8080/myProject/axis/SpringWSEndPoint/sayHello` it doesn't recognize it as a service method ("No service is available at this URL")**

I wonder I have to manually compile the webservice in any .war or .aar file in someway...

Thanks

(I'm running it in tomcat)

Comment: Are you sure that that guide is still actual for learning in 2012?  `ServletEndpointSupport` is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service will accept POST requests to `http://localhost:8080/myProject/axis/SpringWSEndPoint`, but not GET requests to `http://localhost:8080/myProject/axis/SpringWSEndPoint/sayHello`. Axis 1.x doesn't support this request style. However, it supports something like this (for testing purposes): `http://localhost:8080/myProject/axis/SpringWSEndPoint?method=sayHello&message=test`.